# How to dislodge drupal from Apache and remove drupal

Tags: installation

Excuse me please.. I am new to website development. I am using LAMP on fedora 20.
I am also using bluefish to edit html/php.

As a shear experiment, I installed Commerce Kickstart on my system. I did some terrible mistakes and now I need to remove drupal completely from the system..

I was just thinking of deleting the files and dropping the database. but is it enough?

thanks in advance

Comment: That should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, deleting the files and dropping the database should be enough.

If you made any changes to Apache (eg. creating a virtual host) and/or the operating system (eg. a line in the /etc/hosts file) you may want to revert that as well.

Don't worry about messing it up the first time, that's actually a great way to learn and get comfortable with any CMS (not just Drupal).